# custom keyboard flicker when orientation change use the xib

Tags: ios, swift

i have create the custom keyboard extension app. use of autolayout on interface builder(xib). but when change the orientation keyboard flickerring & take much time to open. Is it having any memory issue?

Please suggest the solution...